# Convert Substring to numeric to perform multiplication

Tags: sql, sapb1

Having a bit of a struggle compiling the line for this one.

I have a field, lets say AUD 1200.50, I need to multiply this value by 0.019 but cant because of the AUD.

My best guess was to use substring to remove the leading currency format and then perform the multiplcation, but I will also need to convert it to numeric prior, this is where im getting stuck.

I've tried a few different versions of cast and convert but my current one looks like this

`SELECT convert(decimal,substring('AUD 1,200.50',4,10)) * 0.019`

Ultimately the AUD text value here will be replace with a dynamic syntax field from SAP B1 which will give the same outcome so it will look like this. Keeps giving me an error about converting varchar to numeric.

`SELECT convert(decimal,substring($[$22.0.0],4,10)) * 0.019`

I'm sure im close but just missing it by a bit. Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: Thanks for your response @WOUNDEDStevenJones. It was the comma in the value which was fixed with a replace. If you write it in as the answer I will mark as so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the comma may be breaking the `decimal` conversion. Try removing all commas before converting it to a `decimal`.

```
CONVERT(decimal, REPLACE(SUBSTRING('AUD 1,200.50', 4, 10), ',', ''))
```